# How does one prove $f(g(x))=3f(x)$ in this case?

Tags: functions, polynomials, logarithms, polylogarithm

Prove $f(g(x))=3f(x)$ for:

$f(x)=\log_e \frac{1+x}{1-x}$  and $g(x)=\frac{3x+x^3}{1+3(x^2)}$

I have tried to use formula of $3\log_e x=\log_e x^3$

Comment: you can advantageously use $\ln$ instead of $\log_e$.

Comment: hint : calculate $1+g(x)$ what can you say about $1+3x^2+3x+x^3$ ? Same with $1-g(x)$.

Comment: not that the base of the logarithm matters much here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simple.
\begin{align*}
f(g(x))&=log_e\left[\frac{1+\frac{3x+x^3}{1+3x^2}}{1-\frac{3x+x^3}{1+3x^2}}\right] \\
&=log_e\left[\frac{x^3+3x^2+3x+1}{-x^3+3x^2-3x+1}\right]\\
&=log_e\left[\frac{(x+1)^3}{(1-x)^3}\right]\\
&= 3\,log_e\left[\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right]=3\,f(x)
\end{align*}